# AggressiveInlining Affects C# async Methods Behaviour

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0, methodimplattribute

I have a static field of type `ConcurrentQueue`:

```
static readonly ConcurrentQueue<int> q = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
```

and an async method:

```
static async Task<int?> NextNum()
{
    int? n = await Task.Run<int?>(() =>
    {
        int i = 0;

        if (q.TryDequeue(out i)) return i;
        return null;
    });

    return n;
}
```

Then I execute this code:

```
var nt = NextNum();
q.Enqueue(10);

nt.Wait();
Console.WriteLine("{0}", nt.Result.HasValue ? nt.Result.Value : -1);
```

And the output is `10`.

Now I add `MethodImpl` attribute to my async method:

```
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
static async Task<int?> NextNum()
{
    int? n = await Task.Run<int?>(() =>
    {
        int i = 0;

        if (q.TryDequeue(out i)) return i;
        return null;
    });

    return n;
}
```

And when I execute the previously mentioned code I get `-1`.

Question: Does this mean in an async method the returned Task does not start immediately? And if we add `MethodImpl` (with `AggressiveInlining`) attribute it starts immediately?

I want to know if a method decorated with AggressiveInlining has any effect on task scheduler behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is nondeterministic, so the results may be different based on changes in timings / thread switches / load on the machine / number of cores / etc.

E.g., if you change your test to:

```
var nt = NextNum();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
q.Enqueue(10);
```

then the output is most likely `-1` even without `AggressiveInlining`.

> Question: Does this mean in an async method the returned Task does not start immediately? And if we add MethodImpl (with AggressiveInlining) attribute it starts immediately?

Not at all. The task returned by `NextNum` always starts immediately. However, the task queued to the thread pool by `Task.Run` may not. That's where you're seeing the difference in behavior.

In your original test, the task queued by `Task.Run` happens to take long enough that `q.Enqueue` gets executed before it does. In your second test, the task queued by `Task.Run` happens to run before `q.Enqueue`. Both are nondeterministic, and `AggressiveInlining` just changes the timings.

**Update from comments:**

> I want to know if a method decorated with AggressiveInlining has any effect on task scheduler behavior.

No, it does not.

Comment: If my machine is doing nothing special (and the app just does the test), this test is deterministic and always provide the results that I've mentioned in the post. I have tested and played with this bit of code for some time. I want to know if a method decorated with AggressiveInlining has any effect on task scheduler behavior.

Comment: @kaveh-Shahbazian, that's in debugging mode - that output seems to be "deterministic" in always outputting `10`. But in release mode (Ctrl+F5) your code mostly outputs  `-1` and sometimes, more rarely  `10`. And it is obvious why - the debugging infrastructure mounting takes more time permitting en-queuing before de-queueing

Comment: @KavehShahbazian: If you can add any kind of `Thread.Sleep` to any location and have it *change the outcome*, then the test is not deterministic. Regarding `AggressiveInlining`, the answer is "no, it has no effect on task scheduler behavior."

Comment: @StephenCleary Regardless of what I understand from "deterministic" (I think it's about as long as the initial state is the same we should get same output) so there is a little disagreement here; Please modify the answer and add your comment on task scheduler so I mark it as the answer. Thanks;